# how to fix this error within my table

Tags: fonts, mathbb

[image]

I'm not sure what is going wrong here, i don't see any errors in spelling.

Comment: please always show code as a text block not an image. You have not defined `\mathbb`  usually you need `\usepackage{amsfonts}` This is completely unrelated to the table, you could make an example that just had `\begin{document}$\mathbb{R}$\end{document}`

Answer (score 2):

Some comments about your code, in no particular order:

- Never, ever encase a `table` environment (a "float, in LaTeX jargon) in a `center` environment. If your goal is to center the `tabular` environment that's inside the `table` environment horizontally, you should issue the instruction `\centering` *after* `\begin{table}`.
- Please write `\sin`, `\cos`, and `\ln`, but not just `sin`, `cos`, and `ln`.
- Don't write `e^(\gamma x)` unless you want to raise just the `(` symbol to the superscript position. Instead, write either `e^{\gamma x}` or `\exp(\gamma x)`.
- The `amsfonts` package, which is loaded automatically by the `\amssymb` package, defines `\mathbb`. Load it. Incidentally, the LaTeX error message you've encountered isn't claiming that you spelled `\mathbb` incorrectly.
- Since the table contents are entirely math-y, consider using an `array` environment instead of a `tabular` environment. That way, you don't have to type so many `$` characters, making the code easier to read (and to debug).
- Unless you like to create table layouts that look suspiciously like prison cell windows, don't use vertical rules at all (trust me, they won't be missed), and use fewer but well-spaced horizontal rules, using macros such as `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule` provided by the [booktabs](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs/) package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for \text macro
\usepackage{amssymb}  % for \mathbb macro
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering

$\begin{array}{@{} ll @{}}
\toprule
f(x) & f'(x) \\
\midrule
cx^{\alpha},\ \alpha\ge0,\ c\in\mathbb{R} & \alpha c x^{\alpha-1} \\
\sin(x) & \\
\cos(kx),\ k\ne0 & \\
\exp(\gamma x) & \\
\ln(x)\text{ for $x>0$} & \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}$

\end{table}

\end{document}
```